# In MSSQL, how do you check if a column's values are a substring of another column?

Tags: sql-server, string, join

I have two tables that are unable to be joined on any column. However, in table 1, I have a substring that I want to search against a column in table 2. Below is an example of both tables.

Table 1:

| Name | Substring |
| --- | --- |
| VT 2021-VASA | 2021-VASA |
| BSSTMT, 2021-SSCP | 2021-SSCP |
| LIFEMT, 2021-BMR | 2021-BMR |

Table 2:

| Name |
| --- |
| Vienna 2021-VASA Turner |
| Best Sleep Since, 2021-SSCP |
| LIFE 2021-BMR |

What I would like to accomplish is using the Substring in table 1 to find the names in Table 2 so I can match them with the Names in table 1. Ideally, I would like the results to look like this

| Tbl 1 Name | Tbl 1 Substring | Tbl 2 Match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VT 2021-VASA | 2021-VASA | Vienna 2021-VASA Turner |
| BSSTMT, 2021-SSCP | 2021-SSCP | Best Sleep Since, 2021-SSCP |
| LIFEMT, 2021-BMR | 2021-BMR | LIFE 2021-BMR |

I'm stuck because I can't join the two tables so I really don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest case you can just use `like`

```
select *
from T1
join T2 on T2.name like Concat('%',T1.[substring],'%')
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using this to match the records.

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer using cross apply and patindex:

```
declare @t1 table(name varchar(50),ss varchar(20))

insert into @t1
values
('VT 2021-VASA' ,'2021-VASA')
,('BSSTMT, 2021-SSCP'   ,'2021-SSCP')
,('LIFEMT, 2021-BMR'    ,'2021-BMR')

declare @t2 table (name varchar(50))

insert into @t2
values
('Vienna 2021-VASA Turner')
,('Best Sleep Since, 2021-SSCP')
,('LIFE 2021-BMR')

select *
from @t1 t
cross apply (select t2.name from @t2 t2 where PATINDEX('%' + t.ss + '%', t2.name)>0) ca
```

result:

```
name                 ss         name
VT 2021-VASA        2021-VASA   Vienna 2021-VASA Turner
BSSTMT, 2021-SSCP   2021-SSCP   Best Sleep Since, 2021-SSCP
LIFEMT, 2021-BMR    2021-BMR    LIFE 2021-BMR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table T1(name varchar(50),ss varchar(20))

insert into T1
values ('VT 2021-VASA' ,'2021-VASA')
       ,('BSSTMT, 2021-SSCP'   ,'2021-SSCP')
       ,('LIFEMT, 2021-BMR'    ,'2021-BMR')

create table T2 (name varchar(50))

insert into T2 
values ('Vienna 2021-VASA Turner')
      ,('Best Sleep Since, 2021-SSCP')
      ,('LIFE 2021-BMR')

SELECT *
from T1 t1
inner join T2 t2 on t2.[name] like ('%'+t1.ss+'%')
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: thank you @KeithL for the insert scripts. It was super useful.